# Graphviz - Python : Making node shape into double ellipse with Graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz

I am using [Graphviz 0.5.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) with in my python script, which is similar to this

```
from graphviz import Digraph
dot = Digraph()
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur', shape='ellipse')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise', shape='ellipse')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave', shape='ellipse')

dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')
dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)
```

it renders this:

[image]

By default the shape of the node is an ellipse/oval but I would like to make it a double ellipse, there is a double circle shape but not an ellipse.

I have tried `peripheries = 2` but i'm not sure of the right place to put it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply peripheries to the node properties e.g.

```
graph ethane {
node[ peripheries=5];
     C_0 -- H_0 [type=s];
     C_0 -- H_1 [type=s];
     C_0 -- H_2 [type=s];
     C_0 -- C_1 [type=s];
     C_1 -- H_3 [type=s];
     C_1 -- H_4 [type=s];
     C_1 -- H_5 [type=s];
 }
```

See [chart](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=%20graph%20ethane%20%7B%0D%0Anode%5B%20peripheries%3D5%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20C_0%20--%20H_0%20%5Btype%3Ds%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20C_0%20--%20H_1%20%5Btype%3Ds%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20C_0%20--%20H_2%20%5Btype%3Ds%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20C_0%20--%20C_1%20%5Btype%3Ds%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20C_1%20--%20H_3%20%5Btype%3Ds%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20C_1%20--%20H_4%20%5Btype%3Ds%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20C_1%20--%20H_5%20%5Btype%3Ds%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&cht=gv)

In python if I understand the examples

```
dot.node_attr['peripheries']='5' #whole graph
n.attr['peripheries']='5' #any single node n
```

https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/blob/master/examples/star.py

Comment: if you don't mind me asking again how can I apply it to only one of the nodes and not all of them?